# Tool to integrate responsive HTML plots and slides for presentations

Tags: pdf, html, presentation, powerpoint

In the past, I have always created presentations in Illustrator and exported illustrator slides to PowerPoint for the actual presentation. Any plots or data analysis were exported from the command line or a Jupyter notebook, touched up in Illustrator, and presented in PowerPoint like any other slide.

Recently, the datasets that I have been working with effectively require interactive plots, even for presentations. Plots render beautifully when exported to HTML files and rendered in the browser. Basically, I need either:

- A way to integrate PDF slides and interactive HTML plots, ideally using something like `reveal.js`.
- A way to render my interactive HTML plots in PowerPoint.

I've tried looking but haven't been able to find a straightforward option.